# Problema con google auth provider - React y firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

estoy teniendo un problema con google auth provider y firebase, la cuestion en particular es que a la hora de copiar lo que me brinda la documentacion de firebase, me dice esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La linea donde salta error es esta

```
const Login = () => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();  <--- Aca esta el error 
    const auth = getAuth();
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then((result) => {
        // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        const token = credential.accessToken;
        // The signed-in user info.
        const user = result.user;
        // ...
      }).catch((error) => {
        // Handle Errors here.
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        const email = error.email;
        // The AuthCredential type that was used.
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
        // ...
      });
```

Lo que son las importaciones de firebase las tengo asi:

```
import { getAuth, 
    signInWithPopup, 
    GoogleAuthProvider } 
    from "../../firebase";
```

Y la configuracion de firebase, esta asi:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "x",
  authDomain: "x-x.x.x",
  projectId: "x-x",
  storageBucket: "x-x.x.x",
  messagingSenderId: "2x",
  appId: "x"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);

export const auth = firebase.auth() 
export const googleAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
```

No se que puede estar ocacionando el error, porque yo estoy exportando de forma correcta (o al menos como lo indica la documentacion de firebase)

PD: Esta bien importado dentro de login.jsx lo que es firebase (Al darle control+click me lleva a la ruta correcta)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es por un typo, en el export tienes:

```js
export const googleAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
```

```js
import { getAuth, 
    signInWithPopup, 
    GoogleAuthProvider } 
    from "../../firebase";
```

Si miramos de cerca, en el export dice `google` (con minúscula) mientras que en el import dice `Google` (con mayúscula)

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia, lo arregle pero me sigue pasando lo mismo